# Use phone wireless charging reverse as power source

Tags: power, wireless-charging

How can we use phone wireless charging reverse as power source to light LED or any small device?

Comment: Do you want to power the light or device from the phone or from the wireless charger?

Comment: On the assumption that the phone can feed power out (which at least one handset used to do) then you just need to do the QI handshaking (or whichever wireless power transfer protocol they're using) and then you have power you can put to whatever purpose you want, connecting to a simple LED circuit would be straigh forward.

Comment: Try searching for `qi receiver`: you'll find devices, chips, protocols.

Comment: To clarify, by "phone wireless charging reverse", do you mean "reverse wireless charging"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what you want to do, you may either need a [Qi reciever module/chip](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1901), or it can work without even that (but probably not as you expect). [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g6rI5PJLtx8) shows using a Qi wireless charger to **pulse** LEDs. This is because without a Qi receiver, the charger will not emit power continiously. In the video, you can see that even the NFC coil in the phone can very dimly pulse the LEDs. Reverse wireless charging would probably pulse them brightly, depeding on the detection implementation.

If you dont use a phone, but instead a specific coil and circuit, you can have fully wireless LED dots. Have a look:
[image: LED mouted on a coil, with capacitors to keep it on]
[Souce](https://hackaday.com/2019/05/28/wireless-leds-arent-a-first-but-you-can-make-your-own/)